# Why some iCloud folders do not show up in Finder?

Tags: macos, icloud, finder

The following screenshots both show my iCloud, viewing from Finder and from web. Why some of the folders from web are not there in Finder? **May be I deleted them**, I'm not sure. Anyway, is it possible to see the missing folders (Keynote/Numbers/Pages/Preview) in Finder?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive Options...` and check the boxes for `Keynote/Numbers/Pages/Preview` makes the corresponding folders appear.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed both file explorers should look same:

[image: Finder Screenshot of iCloud Drive]

Apple has this site for iCloud Problem: [Get help with iCloud Drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203052)

Several things are described in the link:

- iCloud correctly activated on your devices ?
- Enough storage ?
- latest Versions ?
- Internet connection ?
- [...]

If those points are fulfilled and the problem still exists, I would take a macOS recovery into consideration.
Recovery is easy with macOS and your files seem to be online and secure as the web browser show the files correctly ([About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)).

Comment: Note: Did you open Pages on your mac or might you have it uninstalled? This might be a cause which came in my mind...

Comment: Yes I openned Pages (and Numbers/Preview too).